# Which type of database structure design is better for performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

MSSQL database. I have issue to create database using old databases data. Old database structure is thousands tables conected with each other by `ID`. In this tables data duplicated many times. Old database tables have more than 50 000 rows (users). Structure like this table

```
Users (id, login, pass, register-date, update-date), 
Users-detail (id, users_id, some data) 
Users-some-data (id, users_is, some data)
```

and this kind of tables is hundreds.

And the question is, which design of db structure to choose, one table with all of this data, or hundreds of tables separated by some theme.

Which type of db structure would be with better performance?

```
Select id, login, pass from ONE_BIG_TABLE
```

or

```
Select * from SMALL_ONLY_LOGINS_TABLE.
```

Comment: Are you saying `Users-detail` and `Users-some-data` never have more than one row for each `users_id`?

Comment: It's bad practice to use * for fields list. Always enumerate them by name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer really depends on the use. No one can optimize your database for you if they don't know the usage statistics.

Correct DB design dictates that an entity is stored inside a single table, that is, the client with their details for example.

However this rule can change on the occasion you only access/write some of the entity data multiple times, and/or of there is optional info you store about a client (eg, some long texts, biography, history, extra addresses etc) in which cases it would be optimal to store them on a child-table.

If you find yourself a bunch of columns with all-null values, that means you should strongly consider a child table.

If you only need to try login credentials against the DB table, a stored procedure that returns a bool value depending on if the username/password are correct, will save you the round-trip of the data.

Comment: The above answer is correct but I would add a caveat. If you find you are having to do lots of joins to build a user profile then i'd consider a single table anyway even if the fields are large. You can use the Execution Plan analysis to work out for yourself the best trade off.

Answer (score 0):

Without indexes the select on the smaller tables will be faster. But you can create the same covering index (id, login, pass) on both tables, so if you need only those 3 columns performance will probably be the same on both tables. 
The general question which database structure is better can not be answered without knowing the usage of your database.

Comment: thank for the answer. What about to select complex data from some other tables. EX: select db1.*, db2.*, db3.* from some_db1,somedb2,somedb3 OR select name, surname, etc from some_one_big_table?

Comment: If you expect an row for each user, than the big table should be quicker.